# recyclerview image snap with big image middle

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can i make recyclerview scroll like image below or have any library i can use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use horizontal LinearLayoutManager :

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

But I think you have to use [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) to achieve exactly the same picture.

Comment: You want just to stay there or to show with scrolling?